# jQuery - removing part of text in table on smaller screens

Tags: jquery, replace, circular-reference

I'm trying to create jQuery to abbreviate a part of my text in a table so it fits more easily on smaller devices. I've tried something like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
$(window).load(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() < 480) {
            $('td:contains("Hertford Hotshots")').text(function() {
                return $(this).text().replace("Hertford Hotshots", "Hotshots");
            });
        }
    });
});
});
```

But it doesn't revert back to the original string when I resize the window over 480px (I have to refresh the page) which is not ideal.

So I have tried:

```
jQuery(function($) {
$(window).load(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() < 480) {
            $('td:contains("Hertford Hotshots")').text(function() {
                return $(this).text().replace("Hertford Hotshots", "Hotshots");
            });
        }
        if ($(window).width() >= 480) {
            $('td:contains("Hotshots")').text(function() {
                return $(this).text().replace("Hotshots", "Hertford Hotshots FC");
            });
        }
    });
});
});
```

But because the text I am changing to at <480px contains the same word  (hotshots), it is creating a circular reference when resizing the page back up! Is there anything else I can try? (Maybe append?)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `jQuery(function($) {
$(window).load(function() {` is too much. just do `$(function() {`

Comment: @mplungjan `window load` is quite different from `dom ready`

Comment: Regardless there is no reason to wrap one in the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(function() {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $('td:contains("Hotshots")').text(function() {
      return $(window).width() < 480?"Hotshots":"Hertford Hotshots";
    });
  });
});
```

This is likely a better idea:

```
$(function() {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $('.resizable').text(function() {
      return $(window).width() < 480 ? 
        $(this).data("short") :  
        $(this).data("long");
    });
  });
});
```

and have

```
<td class="resizable" data-short="Hotshots" data-long="Hertford Hotshots">Hertford Hotshots</td>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't revert back to the original text string when sizing the window back up! :-(